# Modify response headers in SEGW Odata service

Tags: odata, abap, sap-gateway

I have an OData Service Created with SEGW. In my DPC_EXT class I want to modify the response headers.

in other words, before the entityset is returned I want to add my custom header to the response, so that the front-end can handle those custom headers.

I found only the `lo_facade->get_request_header( )` method, but that didn't help me because those are the request headers.

How can I add a custom header to the HTTP response of my entityset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. One should add following code in the redefinition of entityset:

```
DATA: ls_header TYPE ihttpnvp.
ls_header-name = 'ZISM_WARN_MSG'.
ls_header-value = iv_message.
set_header( is_header = ls_header ).
```